# Execute Plugin of Phonegap (Cordova 3.3.0) in Java

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I would like to know how I could call phonegap plugin from java, for example to call the javascript plugin that would desire: "cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'CallListPlugin', 'list', params)"

But if I call it from the MainActivity? without going through the browser?

Regards!

CallListPlugin.java

```
package com.leafcut.ctrac;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;

/**
 * Grab call log data
 * 
 * @author James Hornitzky
 */
public class CallListPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

    /** List Action */
    private static final String ACTION = "list";
    private static final String CONTACT_ACTION = "contact";
    private static final String SHOW_ACTION = "show";
    private static final String TAG = "CallListPlugin";

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.phonegap.api.Plugin#execute(java.lang.String,
     * org.json.JSONArray, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        boolean actionValid = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "Plugin Called");
        if (ACTION.equals(action)) {
            try {
                int limit = -1;

                //obtain date to limit by
                if (!data.isNull(0)) {
                    String d = data.getString(0);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Time period is: " + d);
                    if (d.equals("week"))
                        limit = -7;
                    else if (d.equals("month"))
                        limit = -30;
                    else if (d.equals("all"))
                        limit = -1000000; // LOL
                } 

                //turn this into a date
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(new Date());
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, limit);
                Date limitDate = calendar.getTime();
                String limiter = String.valueOf(limitDate.getTime());

                //now do required search
                JSONObject callInfo = getCallListing(limiter);
                Log.d(TAG, "Returning " + callInfo.toString());
//              result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, callInfo);             
                PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, callInfo);
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
                callbackContext.success();

            } catch (JSONException jsonEx) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Got JSON Exception " + jsonEx.getMessage());
                callbackContext.error(jsonEx.getMessage());
                actionValid = false;
            }
        } else if (SHOW_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            try {
                if (!data.isNull(0)) {
                    viewContact(data.getString(0));
                } 
            } catch (JSONException jsonEx) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Got JSON Exception " + jsonEx.getMessage());
//              result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
                callbackContext.error(jsonEx.getMessage());
                actionValid = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        } else if (CONTACT_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            try {
                String contactInfo = getContactNameFromNumber(data.getString(0));
                Log.d(TAG, "Returning " + contactInfo.toString());
//              result = new PluginResult(Status.OK, contactInfo);
                PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, contactInfo);
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
                callbackContext.success();
            } catch (JSONException jsonEx) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Got JSON Exception " + jsonEx.getMessage());
//              result = new PluginResult(Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
                callbackContext.error(jsonEx.getMessage());
                actionValid = false;
            }
        } else {
//          result = new PluginResult(Status.INVALID_ACTION);
            actionValid = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "Invalid action : " + action + " passed");
        }
//      return result;
        return actionValid;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Directory listing for file, in JSON format
     * 
     * @param file
     *            The file for which we want to do directory listing
     * @return JSONObject representation of directory list. e.g
     *         {"filename":"/sdcard"
     *         ,"isdir":true,"children":[{"filename":"a.txt"
     *         ,"isdir":false},{...}]}
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    private JSONObject getCallListing(String period) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject callLog = new JSONObject();

        String[] strFields = { 
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NEW,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL };

        try {
            Cursor callLogCursor = cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, 
                    strFields,
                    CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">?",
                    new String[] {period},
                    android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

            int callCount = callLogCursor.getCount();

            if (callCount > 0) {
                JSONObject callLogItem = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray callLogItems = new JSONArray();

                callLogCursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    callLogItem.put("date", callLogCursor.getLong(0));
                    callLogItem.put("number", callLogCursor.getString(1));
                    callLogItem.put("type", callLogCursor.getInt(2));
                    callLogItem.put("duration", callLogCursor.getLong(3));
                    callLogItem.put("new", callLogCursor.getInt(4));
                    callLogItem.put("cachedName", callLogCursor.getString(5));
                    callLogItem.put("cachedNumberType", callLogCursor.getInt(6));
                    //callLogItem.put("name", getContactNameFromNumber(callLogCursor.getString(1))); //grab name too
                    callLogItems.put(callLogItem);
                    callLogItem = new JSONObject(); 
                } while (callLogCursor.moveToNext());
                callLog.put("rows", callLogItems);
            }

            callLogCursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("CallLog_Plugin",
                    " ERROR : SQL to get cursor: ERROR " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return callLog;
    }

    /**
     * Show contact data based on id
     * @param number
     */
    private void viewContact(String number) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, 
                Uri.parse(String.format("tel: %s", number)));
        this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);
    }


    /**
     * Util method to grab name based on number
     * 
     */
    private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
        // define the columns I want the query to return
        String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };

        // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
        Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));

        // query time
        Cursor c = cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

        // if the query returns 1 or more results
        // return the first result
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
            c.deactivate();
            return name;
        }

        // return the original number if no match was found
        return number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to import the package above into your main Java file with:

```
import com.leafcut.ctrac.CallListPlugin;
```

After that you should have access to any of the public methods of `CallListPlugin`, example:

```
CallListPlugin.execute(String some_string, JSONArray some_array, CallbackContext some_context);
```